# Encrypting values in a JSON array in data frame

Tags: pyspark, fernet

So we have a struct with an array in a nested struct in a JSON object, so we have column JSON then there is an array type called address in the nested struct. We are looking to encrypt some of these fields using fernet. At moment I have only got this far:

```
df = df.withColumn("json", col("json").withField(arrayPath, transform("json." + arrayPath, lambda x : x.withField(field, encrypt("json." + arrayPath + "." + field, lit(encryptKey))))))
```

Arraypath is the path to the array struct and the field we want to encrypt is in the field variable. I get the error 'TypeError: encoding without a string argument' as I can't drill down to the string value in the encrypt function call, any suggestions?

Comment: what is `encrypt` function? if that's a non-pyspark function then you must make a UDF in order to use it

Comment: encrypt is a udf function that takes in a string and a key

Comment: is `field` nullable?

Comment: no, basically a way I found around this issue is to explode array and put this in another dataframe to grab values and transform